# How to make the first link open a specific link

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have tables that will open links defined in the html, but I would like to make the first link open a different link like: john.com, will be that possible?

so the first name: John will open john.com

html:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Firstname</th>
          <th>Lastname</th>
          <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="person in data">
          <th><a href="">{{person.name}}</a></th>
          <th>{{person.lastName}}</th>
          <th ng-click="colorRow($index)" ng-class="{yellow : $index == row}" ng-show="$index != row ">{{person.email}}</th>
          <th ng-show="$index == row" class="yellow"> Cliked</th>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {
  $scope.row = -1;
  $scope.data = [{
    "email": 'john@example.com',
    name: "John",
    lastName: "Doe"
  }, {
    "email": 'mary@example.com',
    name: "elton",
    lastName: "Junior"
  }, {
    "email": 'july@example.com',
    name: "mark",
    lastName: "Junior"
  }, ]

  $scope.colorRow = function(index) {
    $scope.row = index;
    console.log("Hey Joe", index)
  }
}
```

css:

```
.odd {
  background-color: white;
}

.even {
  background-color: grey;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
  color: green;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/71rqq1o1/22/

Comment: `href="{{ 'http://www.' + person.name + '.com' }}"` ?? See [this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/71rqq1o1/23/)

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer, good point, but I did not explain well, the first link should be different then others like google.com, understand? the others will keep the one defined in the html.

Comment: Use the `$index`: `if ($index) == 0 { // do something else }}`

Comment: thanks, but could you please make a jsffidle, I don't understand :(, sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this by checking `$index` statement in your html file, e.g. like this:

```
<th><a href="{{$index === 0 ? 'http://google.com' : 'http://'+person.name}}">{{person.name}}</a></th>
```

But I would recommend you to keep off the logic from the html file and use something like viewmodels in the html. You have to conform your data in the controller separately.

Something like that:

```
function toViewModel(data) {
  return data.map((d, i) => {
    let obj = {};
    if (i === 0) {
      obj.link = "http://google.com";
    } else {
      obj.link = `http://${d.name}.com`;
    }
    obj.name = d.name;         // you can use some libs to extend objects (e.g. lodash) instead of reassigning each attr
    obj.lastName = d.lastName;
    obj.email = d.email;
    return obj;
  });
}

$scope.viewdata = toViewModel(mydata);
```

And use your viewmodels in the html, just using pure attributes of the objects, without any logic.

```
<th><a href="{{person.link}}">{{person.name}}</a></th>
```